# Much problem/much problems?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Let's say you are describing your future house's space.

> Spaciousness is key so I would not have much **problem/problems** moving around places in the house.

I know that ''problem'' is countable noun, but it seems that the ''problem'' as singular fits the most in the context. **Which should I use then?**

Comment: I  have some problems. I don't have any problems. I would not have too many problems.

Comment: You're quite right that ***problem*** is a countable noun, so you *could* say *I didn't have **many** problems.* You're also quite right that it's perfectly natural to use *singular* in your precise context (you had ***a*** problem, but that problem wasn't very big). I'm not sure how to explain exactly why we use the syntax we do in that context, but the idiomatic standard is *...so I would not have **much of a problem** moving around...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would not have **much problem** with them staying with us for a while.

While this context certainly sounds like "problem" is an uncountable noun, this is actually a colloquialism short for:

> I would not have much **of a** problem with them ...

Either that or it's mixing this with the other common phrase, "much trouble", where "trouble" *is* an uncountable noun.

> I would not have **much trouble** with them ...

That being said, "problem" can apply to all of the *individual* problems associated with some challenge, or the *collective* problem associated with the challenge as a whole.  So, depending on how you want to phrase your statement, any of the following are fine:

> I would not have **any problem** with ...
>
> I would not have **any problems** with ...
>
> I would not have **a problem** with ...

Note we don't usually say:

> I don't have **problems** with

although I couldn't say if this is because it doesn't make sense, or it's just not idiomatic.